is $\Delta$ uniquely defined by translation invariance and its kernel? (other than operators made from $\Delta$)
Consider the space $V = \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{Z}$ of real sequences. I would like to know if there is any linear operator on $V$ that works the same way as the difference operator
$$\Delta = T-1$$
where $T$ is the translation operator
$$T(\dots, x_{-2}, x_{-1}, x_0, x_1, x_2, \dots) = (\dots, x_{-1}, x_0, x_1, x_2, x_3, \dots)$$
while not just being a combination of shifts of $\Delta$. Specifically it should

have kernel $= \operatorname{span}(\dots,1,1,1,\dots)$
be translation invariant ($FT=TF$)
not be of the form $p(T)\Delta$ where $p$ is a polynomial

I have been wondering this for a while and have not been able to prove it either way.
If we could find a basis for $V$ which is closed under translation we could use that to construct a badly behaved invertible translation invariant operator, $F$, so that $F\Delta$ would work. But I cannot tell whether such a basis is possible.
For any translation invariant linear operator $F$ on $V$, $Fe_1$ must be $0$ in all but finitely many coordinates, as otherwise sum coordinates would be infinite sums, which cannot be guaranteed to converge. We can leverage this to show that any such $F$ must restrict to equal $p(T)$ on
$$\bigoplus_\mathbb{Z} \mathbb{R}$$
hence by the kernel condition $F = p(T)\Delta$. But this doesn't seem to guarantee it doesn't behave differently elsewhere in the vector space.

There is a trivial counterexample $T^{-1}-1$.  But there are also nontrivial counterexamples, that are not Laurent polynomials in $T$.
To understand this, it is helpful to think of $V$ as a module over the Laurent polynomial ring $A=\mathbb{R}[x,x^{-1}]$, with $x$ acting as $T$.  I claim that $V$ is divisible as an $A$-module.  Indeed, given a nonzero $f\in A$ and $v\in V$, we may assume that $f$ is a polynomial with a nonzero constant term (since $x$ is invertible).  Then to say that $v=f(T)w$ for some $w$ is just saying that the sequence $v$ satisfies a recurrence relation where $w_{i+n}$ is some linear combination of $w_i,\dots,w_{i+n-1}$ (with nonzero coefficient on $w_i$) minus $v_{i+n}$.  Given values $w_0,\dots,w_{n-1}$, we can use this recurrence forwards and backwards to uniquely determine all the rest of the terms of $w$, to construct $w$ such that $v=f(T)w$.
So, $V$ is a divisible $A$-module.  But since $A$ is a PID, any divisible $A$-modle is injective.  In particular, for instance, this means we can split $V$ as a direct sum $X\oplus Y$, where $X$ is the torsion submodule of $V$ and $Y$ is torsion-free, since the torsion submodule of $V$ is injective.  Also, $Y$ is nontrivial: this just means there exists a sequence $v$ such that $v,Tv,T^2v,\dots$ are linearly independent.  You can construct such a $v$ by recursively choosing its entries to one-by-one make each $T^nv$ linearly independent of $v,Tv,\dots,T^{n-1}v$.  In particular, then, there is an operator $F:V\to V$ that is $\Delta$ on $X$ and the identity on $Y$, and this will satisfy your requirements.
(The same argument works with $\mathbb{R}$ replaced by any field.  On the other hand, if you replace $\mathbb{R}$ with $\mathbb{Z}$, then actually every translation-invariant endomorphism of $\mathbb{Z}^\mathbb{Z}$ is a Laurent polynomial in $T$; this follows from Specker's theorem that every homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}^\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$ factors through the projection onto some finite subproduct.)

Thank you, this is a very neat answer. Would I be correct in assuming it depends on the axiom of choice?

Yes, very much so.  I doubt you can prove the existence of a translation-invariant operator that is not a Laurent polynomial in $T$ without the axiom of choice.
